# php date() и date из mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Только что создал запись в mysqli таблице и автоматом добавилась текущая дата к ней.
Получаю эту дату тут же

Распечатываю `strtotime(ТЕКУЩУЮ ДАТУ)`

Распечатываю `strtotime(ДАТА ИЗ БД, которая даже по виду совпадает с текущей на компьютере)`
Но вот результат:

1648583216 (текущая)

1648586804 (из бд)

Почему текущая отстала от бдшной на 3000+ секунд??

Comment: потому что UTC ........... город сервака - +N часов?

Comment: Потому что в настройках у [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) и [MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934258/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-zone-of-mysql) могут быть выставлены свои временные зоны, а не системные.

Comment: Всё понятно, спасибо, я заработался...